# Anti-symmetric representation of $SO(2n)$ to $SU( n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

in p. 424 of [this book](https://i.4pcdn.org/tg/1459871465465.pdf), it says that
$$
n(2n-1) \text{ anti-sym rep of } SO(2n)$$
$$\to
n^2-1 \text{ adjoint-rep of } SU( n)$$
$$\oplus 1 \text{ of } SU( n)$$
$$
\oplus n(n-1)/2 \text{ anti-sym rep of } SU( n)$$
$$\oplus n^*(n^*-1)/2 \text{ anti-sym rep of } SU( n)
$$

How do we justify the calculations from eq.12?

I can follow the counntings, but not sure the part of
$$
n \otimes_A n^* =?
$$
$$
n^* \otimes_A n =?
$$

> Text from the book:

[image]

Comment: also I wonder does it matter if we choose $U(n)$ or $SU(n)$?

Comment: also I wonder does it matter if we choose $SO(2n)$ or $Spin(2n)$?